# Density of the sum of two random variables with parameters.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I've got a problem from probability theory, which is supposed to have simple theoretical solution. The statement is: "Suggest a probability distribution $(ζ,η)\inℝ^2$, such that random variable $γ = aζ+bη$ has it's density if and only if $ab≠0$"

Let's consider that first random variable $ζ$ has density $f_{ζ}(x)$ and second $η$ has density $f_{η}(y)$. The main equation for that problem, I suppose, is density of sum of two random variables, which is convolution of their densities: $f_{γ}(z) = \int^{-∞}_{+∞}f_{ζ}(ax)f_{η}(z-ax)dx=\int^{-∞}_{+∞}f_{ζ}(z-by)f_{η}(by)dy$.

So we have an expression for density of $γ$, and constants $a$ and $b$ can be taken out from integral sign. But obviously, density would not exist when $ab=0$ only if $a$ and $b$ were somewhere in denominator? How will the particular form of $f_{ζ}(x)$ and $f_{η}(y)$ affect the joint density and when the condition $ab≠0$ will work? I can't figure out clearly the right direction of thinking on that problem. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: "convolution of their densities"... Assuming they are independent.

Comment: Yes, there's no particular condition about dependence/independence in statement. I considered the independent case.

Comment: "I considered the independent case"... And this may not have been the best idea you had--see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any random variable $\theta$ with a density, call this density $f$, choose some $p$ in $(0,1)$ and define some random variables $\zeta$ and $\eta$ by $\zeta=\theta$ with probability $p$, $\zeta=0$ otherwise, and $\eta=\theta-\zeta$.

In other words, $(\zeta,\eta)$ is either $(\theta,0)$ or $(0,\theta)$, with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$ respectively, and independently of $\theta$.

Then neither $\zeta$ nor $\eta$ has a density hence, if $ab=0$, $\gamma=a\zeta+b\eta$ has no density, while, if $ab\ne0$, $\gamma$ has the density 
$$
p|a|^{-1}f(a^{-1}\cdot)+(1-p)|b|^{-1}f(b^{-1}\cdot).
$$
To see why, simply remember that $\gamma=a\theta$ or $\gamma=b\theta$ almost surely.

Note that $(\zeta,\eta)$ is about as far from being independent as can be since $(\zeta,\eta)$ is almost surely in the union of the two axes $\{0\}\times\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\times\{0\}$. The distributions of $\zeta$ and $\eta$ are $pf\,\mathrm{Leb}+(1-p)\delta_0$ and $(1-p)f\,\mathrm{Leb}+p\delta_0$, respectively.

Note also that to assume that $\zeta$ or $\eta$ has a density is to make sure that $\gamma$ has one in some cases when $ab=0$ (consider $(a,b)=(1,0)$) hence such a situation is to be avoided in the context of this exercise.